# How to check if class property is type of List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, typeof

How can I check if an attribute of a class is type of List? The following code snippet is what I want but it doesn't work.

```
class MyClass(val attr:List<String>)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var prop = MyClass::attr
    if(prop.returnType.classifier is List<*>)
        println("Property is type of List")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
prop.returnType.classifier == List::class
```

instead of

```
prop.returnType.classifier is List<*>
```